# @Resource annotation is null at run-time

Tags: java, annotations, resources, glassfish-3

I'm using GlassFish v3.  The following field is declared in a class:

```
@Resource
private javax.sql.DataSource _data_source;
```

The following is declared in web.xml:

```
<data-source>
  <name>java:app/env/data</name>
  <class-name>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</class-name>
  <server-name>localhost</server-name>
  <port-number>3306</port-number>       
  <user>myUser</user>                           
  <password>myPass</password>
</data-source>
```

At run-time _data_source is empty.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if GlassFish supports JSR 250... ?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:app/env/data")
private DataSource _data_source;
```

#### See also

- [DataSource Resource Definition in Java EE 6](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/datasource_resource_definition_in_java)

Comment: I already tried adding lookup, with no luck.  The class containing the declaration is a Server Authentication Module as specified by JSR 196.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pascal's answer: If injection via annotations doesn't work (no Exception occurs, the fields are just null), the problem is often an old deployment descriptor version. For Glasfish v3, you can use:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

Comment: I think that the OP is using a Servlet 3.0 `web.xml` or he wouldn't be able to specify a [Datasource Definition](http://blogs.sun.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/datasource_resource_definition_in_java) in the deployment descriptor.

Comment: My fault, I posted the wrong descriptor... (updated now) But you're right, probably it wouldn't even work to specify the data-source element with the wrong descriptor version. However, I've experienced a similar problem, when trying to inject @EJBs in GFv3: An old descriptor version disabled injection completely.

Comment: My understanding is that GlassFish relies on the DD version to "activate" services so having a "wrong" version might result in unexpected behavior indeed. But I wonder if injection can work without the lookup attribute when using Datasource definition (assuming you are using the appropriate naming convention for the attribute name).

Comment: The web.xml was created by NetBeans 6.8 and looks the same as the one you posted above Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
@Resource(lookup="java:app/env/data")
private DataSource _data_source;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, no xml:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/__default")
private DataSource ds
...
Connection con = null {
try {
  con = ds.getConnection();
  ...
} finally {
  if (con != null) con.close()
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly NOT what the OP wants... The OP wants to leverage datasource definition.

Comment: Yes, I would like to define the database connection parameters in an xml file, so I can change them easily if necessary.